# Rising edge detection sysverilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module syncrisedgedetect(input logic sig_a, rst,clk,output logic sig_a_risedge);

  logic sig_a_d1;

  always @(posedge clk or negedge rst)
  begin
    if(!rst)
      sig_a_d1<=1'b0;
    else
      sig_a_d1<=sig_a;
  end

  assign sig_a_risedge=sig_a & !sig_a_d1;

endmodule
```

Hi, I came across this code in a book regarding rising edge detection for sig_a.
Can anybody explain me its working?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic synchronous edge detection circuit.

The input, `sig_a`, is sampled on each rising edge of the clock, `clk`.  The sampled value is registered; that is, `sig_a_d1` is the value of `sig_a` delayed by one clock cycle.

The output will go to a `1` when there is a rising edge on the input.  The assignment to `sig_a_risedge` is responsible for this.  It says that "there was a rising edge on `sig_a` if the current value is `1` and the value on the previous clock cycle was `0`".

Note that this will only work properly if the frequency of the input signal is lower than that of clock.  If the input goes `0 -> 1 -> 0` all within a single clock period of the sampling clock, the edge may be missed.